# How to use next iterator within a list comprehension in python3 to get a list without any leading zeroes

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, list-comprehension

Trying to remove all the leading zeroes from a list of array using next() and enumerate within a list comprehension. Came across the below code which works. Can anyone explain clearly what the code does.

example : `result = [0,0,1,2,0,0,3]` returns `result = [1,2,0,0,3]`

Edited* - the code just removes the leading zeroes

```
result = result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result)):] 
print(result)
```

Comment: That code does _not_ result in `[0,1,2,3]` from `[0,0,1,2,3]`. It's also totally pointless. `result = [item for item in result if item != 0]`

Comment: @roganjosh: Your alternative removes *all* zeroes, not just leading zeroes. That said, `list(itertools.dropwhile(operator.not_, result))` (or for even more precise equivalence, `list(itertools.dropwhile((0).__eq__, result))`) *would* achieve the same effect *and* would work on arbitrary iterables, not just sequences like `tuple`/`list`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The presented code also removed all leading zeros for me. I am left with `[1, 2, 3]` from the example input

Comment: @roganjosh: Yes, but the OP specified (and their code does) remove *only* leading zeroes. If the input is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5]`, the output should be `[1, 2, 3, 0, 5]`, but your code would produce `[1, 2, 3, 5]`. Their code takes advantage of the "leading only" part to short-circuit as soon as the first non-zero is found; no other value is tested after that point.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have re-read and you're right, but the question doesn't specify this at all. It asks " Can anyone explain clearly what the code does." and says it "works" as though it actually gives the example output (at least as I read it). I still stand by the notion that whatever they found is just needlessly complex (to apparently now not do what they want)

Comment: @roganjosh: Umm... The example is bad at conveying it, but both the title and the first sentence of the question both explicitly mention that the intent is to remove "leading zeroes". The question definitely specifies this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to remove all the leading zeroes from a list of array using
>   next() and enumerate within a list comprehension.

Are you obligated to use `next()`, `enumerate()` and a list comprehension?  An alternate approach:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
from operator import not_ as is_zero

result = dropwhile(is_zero, [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3])

print(*result)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
1 2 0 0 3
%
```

We can potentially explain the original code:

```
result = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3]

result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result)):]
```

By breaking it down into pieces and executing them:

```
enumerate(result)  # list of indexes and values [(i0, x0), (i1, x1), ...]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 3)] 

[i for i, x in enumerate(result)]  # just the indexes
[i for i, x in [(0, 0), (1, 0), ..., (5, 0), (6, 3)]]  # what effectively happens
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0]  # just the indexes of non-zero values
[2, 3, 6]

# not needed with this example input, used to make an all
# zero list like [0, 0, ..., 0] return the empty list []
len(result)  
7

# pull off the first element of list of indexes of non-zero values
next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result))
next(iter([2, 3, 6]), 7)  # what effectively happens 
2

result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result)):]  # slice
result[2:]  # what effectively happens
[1, 2, 0, 0, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks @cdlane, I understand until the last line where result[next(iter([2, 3, 6]), 7:)] - it takes the first value in the generator 2- and how does it change to slice of the original array -  result[2:]? 
Isn't this just result[2] ?
the other default will be evaluated if iteration is exhausted or StopIteration is raised.

Comment: @zack, the expression calculates index `2` which is correct for this input.  It then does `result[2:]`, a *subarray* of the original array.  If it did `result[2]` that would return a *single element* of the array.  The colon `:` tells it we want from index `2` onward.  The `7` argument to `next` doesn't apply because there are non-zero elements in the array.   If there were no non-zero elements, then the '7' kicks in to force `next` to return an empty array.  I.e. it does `result[7:]` (eighth element  onward) which is an empty list `[]` as `result` only has seven elements.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your explanation. It make sense now - I was thinking the ':' inside the next function, but it's not its outside the next function making it a Array slice - I feel so embarrassed i dint notice this :( 
next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result)):
@cdlane - Thank you so much for your help and clearly explaining this inside out. Wish i could learn and contribute to the community like you :)
Saritus ShadowRanger juanpa.arrivillaga roganjosh - Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

So lets unpack the code from inside out.

`(i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0)` is a generator for all indices of values that are not zero.

`next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result))` returns the first value of the generator (so the index of the first value that is not zero). `len(result)` is the default value, if the generator does not return any value. So we could also extract this result into a new variable.

```
index = next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result))
result = result[index:]
```

The last step is a simple list comprehension and only takes values from the list with an index equals or higher than the given one.

Comment: Thank you Saritus!
I understand this "i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0" - gives out the array indices of non zero elements as a generator. 
How does next uses these generator values and the when does it use the default len() and how does the whole thing unpack as indices for the array. Can you please expain further

Comment: "The last step is a simple list comprehension" no, it is a list slice

Comment: Yes it's a slice. @juanpa.arrivillaga - can you please clarify how the generator is used within next and how the actual result takes in two arguments here 

1) next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0)
2) len(result)):

Comment: @zack: `next` in two-arg form pull the very next value from an iterator and returns it; if the iterator is exhausted, it returns the second argument (the default). So all `next` does is get the first item (the index of the first non-zero element) or the length of the sequence if all elements are zero. Saritus's second code block shows that by itself, it gets an index, then plugs that into the slicing syntax to pull everything from that index onwards.

Comment: @zack have you consulted the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)?